# Regular expression to split a string (which contains newline characters) into equal length chunks

Tags: c#, regex

I have got a string let's say
Test Subject\r\nTest Comments...
I want to write a regular expression which would split the string to chunks of n characters say n=6 and the split process should not be affected by newline characters (\r\n).

The code which i have come up with is

```
string pattern = ".{1," + 6 + "}";
string noteDetails = "Test Subject\r\nTest Comments...";
List<string> noteComments = Regex.Matches(noteDetails, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();`
```

But the output which i am getting is

```
Test S
ubject

Test C
omment
s...
```

The desired output is

```
Test S
ubject
\r\nTe
st Com
ments.
..
```

If \r\n is not present then the code works fine. The bottom line is \r\n should also be considered as normal characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to convert all CR and LF to `\n` and `\r` strings? Then, before running a regex, do it manually, `noteDetails = noteDetails.Replace("\n", @"\n").Replace("\r", @"\r");`

Comment: Are you trying to encode the CR and LF?  If not then the third entry shoudl be `\r\nTest` because `\r` and `\n` are both a single character, not two.

Comment: Does this work for you? `(?:.|\r|\n){1,6}`

Comment: Depending on what you want you might also need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Comment: Do you need regex for this? C# is very capable of counting characters in a string. Especially with indexes...

Comment: Why not just `string.Replace`? Much more readable than a regex and easier to deal with for something this basic.

Comment: Thank you @juharr your suggestion worked

Comment: @DetectivePikachu `string.Replace` makes no sense here.  The alternative would be to use a loop and `string.Substring`.

Comment: You're right that should say `string.Substring`, though there is no reason to loop for this. Just use LINQ

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex.  Use string methods :

```
            string input = "Test Subject\nTest Comment";

            string[] results = input.ToCharArray()
                .Where(x => x != '\n')
                .Select((x, i) => new { chr = x, index = i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / 6)
                .Select(x => string.Join("", x.Select(y => y.chr)))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you filtering `\n`?  It seems like the OP wants to include all characters.

Comment: Just an option just in case OP needs it.

Answer (score 1):

A second more traditional approach, because Regex is rarely the best choice:

```
    var stringToSplit = @"Test Subject\r\nTest Comments...";

    var length = stringToSplit.Length;
    var lineLength = 6;

    var lastIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length - lineLength ; i+= lineLength)
    {
        lastIndex = i;
        Console.WriteLine(stringToSplit.Substring(i, lineLength));
    }
    if (lastIndex < length)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine(stringToSplit.Substring(lastIndex + lineLength, (length - (lastIndex + lineLength))));
    }
```

And the output:

```
Test S
ubject
\r\nTe
st Com
ments.
..
```